# Open more then 1 connection at the same time MSSQL-NODE

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Im using mssql with npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql
for the start i needed to insert to only one table.
so this is how i used:

```
const pool_db1 = await sql.connect(config);
pool.request()
.input('input_parameter',element.CustomerID)
.query('INSERT ..')
```

Now i need to insert some data for one more table that located in different Databases.

So basically i have 2 configs files.
i tried to add

```
    const pool_db1 = await sql.connect(config);
    const pool_db2 = await sql.connect(config2);
```

i know i can SQL.close() one connection and then sql.connect() to another,
 but i want another solution because this INSERT to tables happend async for more tables(in the same connection), 
so i need those 2 connection to be open but it dosent seems to open 2 connection.
error below:

> (node:13888) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Global connection already exists.
>   Call sql.close() first. warning.js:18 (node:13888) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when you use `sql.conenct` you are using the lib in a global scope way, checking [docuemntation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connection-pools) I found the `ConnectionPool` method, try:

```
const pool_db1 = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect();
const pool_db2 = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config2).connect();
```